# MongoDB / Mongoose Unit Testing - Best practice?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm writing a npm package to import GIS data into MongoDB via mongoose. I've written unit tests using mocha to test the data transformations that happen BEFORE the mongoose model is saved.

I'd like to be sure that all the mongoose data got saved correctly to the database (including any updates that needed to occur). What would be the best practice, in this case?

My intuition create a test collection, insert all the records, ensure that it looks the way I expect it to look, and drop the collection.

Comment: Request for tool/libraries suggestions have been removed. Is this still considered "off-topic"? 

It is a generic question regarding unit testing practices in MongoDB, which I consider to be within the scope of a fair SO question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, setting up and tearing down all the collections in the database is necessary for ensuring there are no side effects between unit tests. In practice, this means a `beforeEach()` where you reconnect to the database and drop all collections, and an `afterEach()` where you disconnect from the database.

Some deeper information: What you are trying to do here is `integration testing`, where you are testing the actual integration between your code and `mongo`. `Unit tests` are tests that never call the database or other resources. More info on this here: [What's the difference between unit tests and integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357601/whats-the-difference-between-unit-tests-and-integration-tests) For me, I separate them into `tests/unit` and `tests/integration`.

I'm not aware of any packages or libraries that do this for you, but take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.scotchmedia.com/tutorials/express/authentication/1/06) for one way to go about this.

Comment: So not only create a new collection, but a whole new test database? Got it.

Comment: Almost—in that tutorial the database is never dropped, but all of its collections are removed.