# Can't load messages.properties when running test on IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, junit

Test configuration for loading `messages.proeprties` is

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource" p:basenames="classpath:i18n/messages,classpath:i18n/application" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>
```

If I run a single test on Intellij (Junit test runner), it won't be able to load `messages.properties` from `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/messages.properties`.

Running the same test from console (`mvn -Dtest=blablatest test`) works.

In order to make it work on Intellij, I have to copy the `messages.properties` to `src/test/resources/i18n/messages.properties`.

**Update1**: *"Running the same test from console (`mvn -Dtest=blablatest test`) works."*
Works only if the project is built first.

Comment: `src/main/webapp` isn't the class path. You should put them in `src/main/resources` instead for `classpath:` to pick them up.

Comment: if the purpose of your test is testing messages.properties itself (unlikely) you can follow the M.Deinum suggestion. If the purpose of your test is testing *something* that needs a messages.properties I would not rather add src/main/resources as classpath of my tests but I'd have a different set of *.properties only for test purposes instead.

Comment: @medveshonok117 The purpose of the testing is something that needs a `messages.properties`.
If I put it in `src/main/resources` it's ok for the unit test but the thing is that by default the messages properties for the project is `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/messages.properties`.

Comment: OK, so my point is that you *do not* want your tests to load messages.properties from the main classpath: the correct approach is leaving completely separated your "live" and unit test environments.

Comment: @medveshonok117 I don't need different messages for testing purposes, why should I use a separate file in that case, placed in test resources and maintain two files? Why is that the correct approach?

Comment: Unit tests *usually* do not require to run against *production* configuration - this is the job of integration tests - but using mocked / stubbed configuration / data instead. Giving the test environment the visibility to production (or any other non-test) configuration may lead to further problems (e.g. database / jms unwanted connections to wrong servers).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357601/whats-the-difference-between-unit-tests-and-integration-tests

If you find "correct approach" too much restrictive you can see this as "best practice".

Comment: agree, just was hopping you'd have some interesting reference.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could add src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n to test resources: File > Project Structure ... > Project Settings > Modules

Comment: thanks. It works for Intellij this way but I realised (see update) that it's not working properly when I run the test form maven, e.g.  
`mvn clean;`  
`mvn -Dtest=blablatest test`