# Laravel Unit Test Controller

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

How can i test my function which has __construct ?

For ex my controller code looks like :

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers; 
    use App\Repositories\UserAccountRepository;
    class UserController extends ProtectedController
    {
      protected $userAccountRepository;
      public function __construct(userAccountRepository 
      $userAccountRepository){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->userAccountRepository = $userAccountRepository;
    }

    public function FunctionWantToTest(){
        return 'string';
    }
```

The unit test required to fulfill the construct first before test my FunctionWantToTest.

So, my test code looks like,

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testUserList()
    {

        $UserController = new UserController(???what value??);
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Need more help (best practice) how to test the code which has construct.

Comment: I would recommend feature tests for controllers (more-so routes which use controllers), not unit tests.

Comment: would you show me an example ? @Devon

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/http-tests

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use `app->make`:

```
class UserTest extends TestCase
{

    protected $userController;

    public function setUp() {

        parent::setUp();

        $this->userController = $this->app->make(UserController::class);
    }

    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testUserList()
    {
        $this->userController // do what you need here...
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you tell me, 
1. what for is setUp() ? is this default ?
2. what is this ? $this->app->make(UserController::class);
3. what can i do here? $this->userController // do what you need here...

Answer (score 0):

Use feature test or integration test when test controller,

You can see this brief explanation about unit test and integration test.

[What's the difference between unit tests and integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357601/whats-the-difference-between-unit-tests-and-integration-tests)