# Is unit testing just testing methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I'm a new software developer and the devs are going over the importance of Java Unit Testing. Is Unit Testing just testing the individual java methods? And what is integration testing in relation to unit testing in Java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between unit tests and integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357601/whats-the-difference-between-unit-tests-and-integration-tests)

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing would be something as simple as a testing addition capability of a software by testing out it's function. Integration testing would be when you add another function or module and then you are testing the functionality that you intended.